# My Array made of objects doesn't accepted map method (using React function)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function, react-hooks

I have an array inside a state, but when I try to use the map method on it, I get the `.map is not a function error`

Some info:

```
const [movies, setMovies] = useState ('')

    useEffect (()=>{
      ApiPopularMovies().then ( (data) => {
          setMovies(data.results) / / the array of objects
      })
    }, [])

console.log(movies): 

    Array(20) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
    ​
    0: Object { adult: false, backdrop_path: "/jlGmlFOcfo8n5tURmhC7YVd4Iyy.jpg", id: 436969, … }
    1: Object { adult: false, backdrop_path: "/swcF9sPlruc6s4gAHuWfbYicbqG.jpg", id: 675445, … }
    2: Object { adult: false, backdrop_path: "/7WJjFviFBffEJvkAms4uWwbcVUk.jpg", id: 451048, … }
    3: Object { adult: false, backdrop_path: "/lzLzKXq2C0kL5Pu7VW5sNl5KV6L.jpg", id: 597433, … }
    4: Object { adult: false, backdrop_path: "/uHmvk8FnoxpgujDU0RIXLkv2fNt.jpg", id: 573164, … }
    5: Object { adult: false, backdrop_path: "/npYe4umAU5ihbj6aqsRRnzF9EKg.jpg", id: 706972, … }
    6: Object { adult: false, backdrop_path: "/dq18nCTTLpy9PmtzZI6Y2yAgdw5.jpg", id: 497698, … }
    7: Object { adult: false, backdrop_path: "/8s4h9friP6Ci3adRGahHARVd76E.jpg", id: 379686, … }
    8: Object { adult: false, backdrop_path: "/j28p5VwI5ieZnNwfeuZ5Ve3mPsn.jpg", id: 550988, … }
    9: Object { adult: false, backdrop_path: "/xXHZeb1yhJvnSHPzZDqee0zfMb6.jpg", id: 385128, … }
    10: Object { adult: false, backdrop_path: "/wjQXZTlFM3PVEUmKf1sUajjygqT.jpg", id: 581726, … }
    11: Object { adult: false, backdrop_path: "/yizL4cEKsVvl17Wc1mGEIrQtM2F.jpg", id: 588228, … }
    12: Object { adult: false, backdrop_path: "/gX5UrH1TLVVBwI7WxplW43BD6Z1.jpg", id: 459151, … }
    13: Object { adult: false, backdrop_path: "/620hnMVLu6RSZW6a5rwO8gqpt0t.jpg", id: 508943, … }
    14: Object { adult: false, backdrop_path: "/rUoGZuscSG4fQP3I56ndadu2A8E.jpg", id: 729720, … }
    15: Object { adult: false, backdrop_path: "/9p3bwHTpX5Axpyp4gxqmDxWaau0.jpg", id: 410113, … }
    16: Object { adult: false, backdrop_path: "/qnFxKwYDY7vfc3DBu3m8DzhhCfw.jpg", id: 678580, … }
    17: Object { adult: false, backdrop_path: "/nprqOIEfiMMQx16lgKeLf3rmPrR.jpg", id: 619297, … }
    18: Object { adult: false, backdrop_path: "/uaOiyRpwunmD7PH5y5A5Ag0uutf.jpg", id: 847981, … }
    19: Object { adult: false, backdrop_path: "/tehpKMsls621GT9WUQie2Ft6LmP.jpg", id: 602223, … }

    length: 20

    <prototype>: Array []

  movies.map(item => console.log(item))
```

`TypeError: movies.map is not a function`

Comment: Can you show us the full component? Or if it's large, at least the essential parts that interact with `movies` (in particular any calls to `setMovies`). I suspect that at some point the state is being set to a non-array value - but without seeing the code, it's impossible to tell how and where.

Comment: Is `useState (Array)` literal? Because `Array` is a function, not an array. So you'd get that error the first time you tried to use it, but not later after you've done `setMovies` with an actual array. You'd want `useState([])` instead. You definitely won't get the error you describe if `movies` really is an array.

Comment: update the question with the useEffect and the function api Call, i'm using an response of api, data.response is the Array

Comment: wow, Nicholas, that was IT, I thought that when I set the SetState the contents were replaced, I didn't think it mattered whether or not the array was declared initially. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

for who get the same error: replace the initial state strings '' for an Array [] instead.